# Get textbox from Button Tag

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I try to get a `TextBox` from a `Button.Tag`.

I have X buttons and for every `Button` has a own `TextBox`.

Not I want one Click-Method for all buttons and get the correct `TextBox` from the `Button.Tag`, but this does not work.

Can someone help me with this?

```
 Dim Textbox As TextBox = CType(DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag, TextBox)
 Textbox.Text = ""
```

With this code I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: "Das Objekt des Typs "System.String" kann nicht in Typ "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" umgewandelt werden."

Comment: So, do you want to click all of the buttons, while the user only clicked one button?

Comment: What do you mean by "this want work"? Any error message/exception?

Comment: No, the form has e.g. 10 Buttons and 10 textboxes, for every Button one Textbox, the Tag from the Buttons has the exact Name from the Textbox. So I will have one Click. Sub for allt the Buttons. The Sub should get the correct Textbox from the Button Tag a set the .Text value

Comment: I have update the question with the error Message

Comment: Can you also add the code where you assign the `TextBox` to the `Button.Tag`? It seems you assigned the name of the `Textbox` instead of the `TextBox` itself

Comment: I do this in the designer, Yes i set the name from the textbox in the Tag grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to convert a `String` (name of the `TextBox`) into a `TextBox`, which won't work.

So you either have to assign the `TextBox`'es by code like this:

```
Button1.Tag = TextBox1
Button2.Tag = TextBox2
...
```

or find the `TextBox` by its name like this:

```
Dim Textboxname As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag.ToString()
Dim Textbox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(Textboxname, True).First(), TextBox)
Textbox.Text = ""
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first solution :)